# jQuery - assign self in .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way to safely assign an element in it's own .data() attribute using jQuery? Using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myDiv").data("element",this);
    var el = $('#myDiv').data('element');
});
```

gives for `el` just the `#document` instead of the actual element.

I know this could be avoided by using
    `$("#myDiv").data("element",$("#myDiv")[0]);`

But I want a more waterproof method, that doesn't require to fill in the 
    `$('#myDiv')` twice.

The only solution I found so far is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var el_original = $("#myDiv")[0];
    $("#myDiv").data("element",el_original);
    var el = $('#myDiv').data('element');
});
```

Which works, but I'm not completely satisfied.

In advance thanks for any tips anyone has, and sorry if I sounds a bit noob-ish.

Comment: why do you need this? you should be always able to access the dom element?

Comment: If the reference to `#myDiv` is already available, why would you want to fetch it again from data?

Comment: Seems like your last method accomplished what you want, but it’s a pretty odd thing to do - why do you want to access the element by `$('#myDiv').data('element')` instead of `$('#myDiv')[0]`?

Comment: @DanielA.White, @Timir, @BenWest this example is very oversimplified. On my site Im assigning a whole object to the `myDiv` element (a canvas), along with a function that uses the element to draw in. If I use `this` inside the function, which is inside the object, which is in the data tag I can't get to the element, so I have to save it somewhere.

Comment: @JipG just use a closure. Or reselect it with jaunty

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that. Could you please clarify?

Comment: My eventual goal is to have something like this
`$("#myCanvas").data("graph",{
el: this/*element*/,
draw: function() {
el = this.el;
/*do stuff here with element*/
}
})
$("#myCanvas").data("graph").draw();`

Comment: Use bind or look up how closures work

Comment: @DanielA.White Alright will do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
$.data($("#myDiv").get(0), "element", $("#myDiv").get(0));
```